# why php post global variable iis not working

Tags: php, post

Faculty's server's $_post[] global variable doesnt work.Is there anybody knows the reason why is not working?

`<form action="" method="POST">
<input name="asd" type="text" value="mesaj">
<input type="submit" name="eray" >
</form>`

`<?php
 echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ;
var_dump($_POST["asd"]);

echo $_POST["asd"]; ?>`

I recieved null and posts in the result of this example. 
I also want to share phpinfo but it s forbiden.

`echo error_reporting(E_ALL);` result is 22519

BTW get global is certainly working.

if

`$_POST["asd"]="Working !!";
echo $_POST["asd"];`

i recieved "Working !!" i dont understand. i think form doesnot submitted

Comment: is the form actualy posted?

Comment: you forgot to add $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] on your form action attribute.

Comment: @Miks, exactly. I think that should solve it.

Comment: if action is blank it will post to itself so theres really no need to do that

Comment: @Miks  has absolutely nothing to do with it

Comment: @Miks i try but but it did not , @Daniel A. form is posted but `$_POST["asd"] is null`

Comment: well in that case there must be something wrong on your php environment why try to uninstall and re-install it again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
echo var_dump($_POST["asd"]);
```

which produces an error because

```
echo var_dump
```

is wrong/doesn't exist.
Needs to be

```
var_dump($_POST["asd"]);
```

only

Then check your php.ini for those lines:

```
post_max_size = 8M
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

and check if those modules are running

```
RadCompression 
RadUploadModule
```

Comment: i try but but it did not

Comment: php.ini is secret to us , its forbidden

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: i mean php.ini is not accessible,i dont have the authority to checked the php.ini.

Comment: if you create a file with <?php phpinfo(); ?> you can't access it in your browser?

Comment: phpinfo is forbidden access

Answer (score 0):

Var dump is not echo-able

remove the echo and retry like this :

```
var_dump($_POST["asd"]);
```

have a good day !

Comment: i try but but it did not

Comment: var_dump is disabled ?
try print_r($_POST);

Comment: i try and i recieved `Array()`

Comment: So your form doesn't send any data.
Try with GET just for test.

and try to put and URL in the action in your form

Comment: Check if the enable_post_data_reading is enabled in your php.ini

and if you can't have any access try to put this in an .htaccess

php_flag enable_post_data_reading 1

Comment: ".htaccess php_flag enable_post_data_reading 1 " i try this but i recieved "The page you are trying to connect has been blocked because it contained incorrect code or pose a risk to the server!"

Answer (score 0):

you should also set this up a bit better so you dont potentially confuse yourself by looking at an empty $_POST array before you submit the form

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

     print_r($_POST);

} else {
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST"> <input name="asd" type="text" value="mesaj">
    <input type="submit" name="eray" > </form>
    <?php 
}
```

or test this

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

     print_r($_REQUEST);

} else {
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST"> <input name="asd" type="text" value="mesaj">
    <input type="submit" name="eray" > </form>
    <?php 
}
```

or this

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

     print_r($_GET);
     print_r($_REQUEST);

} else {
    ?>
    <form action="" method="GET"> <input name="asd" type="text" value="mesaj">
    <input type="submit" name="eray" > </form>
    <?php 
}

?>
```

Comment: change to print_r($_REQUEST) ... if no dice there then change the form method to GET just to see what happens .. see my edits

Comment: get is working i recived  "Array ( [asd] => mesaj [eray] => Gönder ) Array ( [asd] => mesaj [eray] => Gönder [__utma] => 2076688....."

Comment: post is not working i recieved "Array ( [__utma] => 207668870.1749987435.1411220659.141......"